# AES 256 decryption from C# net to Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption

I am in need to convert below C# code to java , i have tried the possible ways and could not find the correct solution the result of the bot are quite different, In C# we get the correct data but in the Java value result is binary data. The Decryption technique used is AES 256 , May i know where i am going wrong in the java code.

```
public static string AESDecryptText(string input, string key)
{
    // Get the bytes of the string
    byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    keyBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(keyBytes);

    byte[] bytesDecrypted = AESDecrypt(bytesToBeDecrypted, keyBytes);

    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);

    return result;
}

private static byte[] AESDecrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] keyBytes)
{
    byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

    // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
    // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(keyBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return decryptedBytes;
}
```

Java Code for the above C# program

```
byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

final String KEY = "zszQ1nI8wT8XEcNONtbsbkgGRMLNFrq/X7+FBafQZn8=";

String pin = "pvdDFINyKi1DhgZmxCSvwVIR4TKhEI/momrLpGS3DB8=";

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(KEY.toCharArray(), salt,
            1000, 384);

Key generatedKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

byte[] extractedKey = new byte[32];
byte[] iv = new byte[16];


System.arraycopy(generatedKey.getEncoded(), 0, extractedKey, 0, 32);
System.arraycopy(generatedKey.getEncoded(), 32, iv, 0, 16);

byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(pin);

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(extractedKey, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));

byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decoded);

System.out.println("Result " + new String(decValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Too broad!. You should tell us, what is going wrong and where. We then might be able to help you. It seems, you do not know how to find out where your program misbehaves. Time to learn debugging ...

Answer (score 0):

Be confident that given the same parameters for a standardized algorithm like AES, the results will be exactly the same.  Remember there are quite a few parameters that must all match.  In this case, it looks like the Java version of your code overrides the padding parameter, while the C# version uses the default. 
 Within the debugger, review all the properties and make sure they match.